# How do I remove IIS 7?

Tags: iis-7

I am running Windows Vista Ultimate. I went to the add/remove Windows components tool and unchecked "Internet Information Services." However, when I access http://localhost/ the IIS 7 default page is still shown. I would expect no response.

Comment: are you sure your browser isn't serving up a cached page?  try emptying your browser's cache, or use a different browser.

Comment: also make sure you have rebooted after you removed it.  If it was running when you removed it, it might not have been stopped first.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your comment to LuckyLindy's answer, it seems you already tried removing it from Vista's add/remove programs, AND you disabled the service, yet you're still getting a response from localhost.

Assuming it's not a browser caching thing, you may want to use a tool like [TcpView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) to determine which process is listening on port 80.  It could be something other than IIS 7 that's listening and responding.

Answer (score 1):

1. first of all uninstall IIS from your system .Open Add/remove
   programs option in control panel.click on Add/Remove Windows Component
   then uncheck Internet Information system.
2. then delete inetpub folder
3. restart your system
4. now reinstall your IIS

this will definetly solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't uninstall it, you could disable the service, which would at least ensure that IIS wasn't running.

Comment: Well, before trying to uninstall it I did disable the service. It was _still_ running. Now, I have to reinstall it to get the service listed in the services list.

Comment: in that case, your browser is a liar, don't believe it!

Answer (score 0):

i had tried to disable iis via program and feature but not complete to removed.